# What does one integral tell for two variable function?

Tags: integration

Let's assume I have function:

$
f(x,y)
$

Solving double integral:
$
\int \int f(x,y)\ dx\ dy
$ would give me volume of this body function. For example cubic centimeters.

But what if I use only one integral:

$
\int f(x,y)\ dy$

What do I get out then? A volume, an area? I have hard time to visualize this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a function of x. For example, if you were integrating over some 2D domain, this would be a function yielding the length of the line in the y direction at a fixed x.

Answer (score 2):

$\int f(x,y)dy$ is still a function of $x$.  You could define it as $g(x)$ up to a constant of integration.  When the double integral gives you a volume it needs to be a definite one.  If you use a particular range of $y$ for this integral, $g(x)$ has no arbitrary constant.